# Specifying Multiple Formats with one .format()

Tags: python, string, formatting

I'm trying to specify multiple formats using Python's `.format()`.

I would like the sign to be shown, rounded to 2 significant digits, and right justified with a width of 17.

Right now I have:

```
print(
'''
Number of vowels before:{0[vowel_count]:>13}
Number of vowels after:{1[vowel_count]:>14}
Conversion Change:{2:>17+.2f}%
'''.format(before, after, vowel_change)
)
```

but I get an error:

```
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

because '2:>17+.2f' is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `+` from the format string:

```
>>> print("Conversion change: {0:>17.2f}%".format(3.14159))
Conversion change:              3.14%
```

or, if you want it, put it just after the align specifier, before the width:

```
>>> print("Conversion change: {0:>+17.2f}%".format(3.14159))
Conversion change:             +3.14%
```

For further information, consult the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) of the format specification mini-language.